# React: how to work with the database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm studying react.js.

How to correctly add class 'use' to the element where the click occurs? From other elements it needs to be removed.

How to get rid of the index, but be able to handle and dispose of the items?

```
var DB = [

    {
        name: 'Имя 1', url: 'http://localhost:1', use: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Имя 2', url: 'http://localhost:2', use: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Имя 3', url: 'http://localhost:3', use: false
    }
];

class SideBarEl extends React.Component {
    hoverLi(t){
        if(t.target.id !== ''){
            for (var i = 0; i < DB.length; i++){
                if(t.target.id == i){
                    DB[i].use = true;
                } else {
                    DB[i].use = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    render(){
        var newsTemplate = DB.map(function(item, index) {
            return (
                <li key={ index } id={ index } onClick={ this.hoverLi.bind(this)} className={ item.use ? 'use' : '' }>
                    { item.name }
                    <span>
                        { item.url }
                    </span>
                </li>
            )
        }, this);
        return(
            <ul>{newsTemplate}</ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 Set `this.state`

You need to use React `state` to handle such things and rerender when action occurs. If you just use a variable, React doesn't know when something should be rerendered.

```
this.state = {
  links: [
    {
      name: "Имя 1",
      url: "http://localhost:1",
      use: true
    },
    {
      name: "Имя 2",
      url: "http://localhost:2",
      use: false
    },
    {
      name: "Имя 3",
      url: "http://localhost:3",
      use: false
    }
  ]
};
```

Read more about state on https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

## 2 Update state by using `onClick`

```
handleClick(item) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    links: prevState.links.map(link => {
      link.use = link === item;
      return link;
    })
  }));
}

render() {
  // rest of code...
  <li
    key={item.url}
    id={index}
    onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}
    className={item.use ? "use" : ""}
  >
  // rest of code...
}
```

For only 3 links it's okay to have such non-optimized code. If you would like to apply this for big collection of links (hundreds or thousands of links), it will require a bit more work but probably it's out of you question's scope.

## 3 Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/mQoomVOmA

If you click on a link, it will be red and rest will be black because I added this small CSS `.use { color: red; }`

Have fun and happy coding.